# SharePoint Search rest api query Or operator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365, office-365-develop-tool

In office 365 I get Search results using the following query

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title: Design'
```

What I would like to be able to do is add an or condition for more than one properties in the query text e.g. If I need to search files that have a property Name i.e.`'Filename'` using the following query

```
'https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='FileName: Design'
```

I get File 1, File 2, file 3

Now if I search for Title

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title: Design '
```

e.g I get File 2 File 5, File 6

I need to get all the files not just the common files in the search.

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title: Design + FileName: Design'
```

Adding the + operator gives me only results common in both the queries

I apparently need to do

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title:Design plus results of Filename:Design'
```

So that i get File 1, File 2, file 3, File 5, File 6

Is there any other way to build queries instead of using the method above.

Comment: Try `querttext='or(Title: Design,FileName: Design)'`

Comment: Thank you for the response I tried it, but does not work with for querttext='or(Title: Design*,FileName: Design*)  instead querttext=Title: Design OR FileName: Design* worked.  Is the wildcard character the issue here.

Comment: I have a file with some custom properties in Shared Documents folder in sharepoint and also I need to search the file using the custom properties in rest api php, I also tried the above example but its not showing any results but showing some reponses

Comment: The OR operator worked for me too. Thanks @user1339913